# Hierarchical Clustering Guidance

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data set of OrderIDs that are open and a data set of OrderIDs that have been filled.  Each set has many attributes, all are the same in both.  My goal is to use python to create a subset of filled orders that match as closely as possible with each open order (one open order to many filled orders).  I am bringing in my data in from CSVs and merging them inside python.

I could really use help on how to classify the data and how to create the hierarchical clustering algorithm.  Any help you can provide would be great!